# LateX equation issue - use of brackets?

Tags: formatting, latex, equation

I am struggling with this equation:

```
\begin{equation}\label{planewave}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{E} \quad & = \quad \textbf{u}_{1} E_{0} e^{i(wt-\textbf{k\cdot r})} \\[5pt]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

Somehow it's not compiling even though I don't se any obvious error in the bracketing!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: It actually compiles ok for me in the ShareLatex platform

Comment: This is the error I get:  `Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.103 ...bf{u}_{1} E_{0} e^{i(wt-\textbf{k\cdot r}
                                                  )} \\[5pt] ` I'm using Overleaf.com

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! Posting here in case it can be useful to anyone in the future! :)

```
\begin{equation}\label{planewave}
\begin{aligned}
\textbf{E} \quad & = \quad \textbf{u}_{1} E_{0} e^{i(\omega t-\textbf{k} \cdot \textbf{r})} \\[5pt]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```